# Configure the postcss module loader in Next.js to convert kebab case classes

Tags: next.js, postcss, css-modules, react-css-modules

It seems like you can configure webpack's css loader to convert the classnames in stylesheets from kebab case to camel case (see here https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#localsconvention)

How can I configure Next.js to achieve this?

I've tried modifying the webpack config like this, but it breaks the app:

```
module.exports = {
  // Modify webpack config
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.module\.css$/i,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            localsConvention: 'camelCase',
          },
        },
      ],
    })

    return config
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a live issue in Next.js and there is an ongoing discussion about it (for a long time):
[CSS modules - converting class names to camelCase automatically #11267](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11267)

I've just run into this issue recently and didn't find any solutions yet, unfortunately.